# How does SPM integrate with Xcode 10.2+?

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage, swift-package-manager, xcode11

I currently use Carthage for dependency management in Xcode projects. I'm giving Swift Package Manager a try, but it seems to want to build projects via command line only and with a specific file structure, not via Xcode.

I've added the Package.swift file, and if I'm starting a new project, I can get add the dependencies integrated via generating a new Xcode Project just fine:

```sh
swift package update
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

But if I have an existing project, I don't want it to be overwritten.

Maybe I'm expecting a Carthage replacement and that's not what SPM is? It would be nice to get dependency management built into Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. Rather than delete the question, I'll keep it here in the hopes it benefits others.

**Answer: Xcode 10 does not support Swift Packages.** That feature is upcoming in Xcode 11 (in [Beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_3_release_notes) at the time of this note). *And it looks slick!*

On Xcode 11, while on a project, you open up from the Menu: *File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency*. On the dialog prompt, you enter the Repository URL and which version, branch or commit you want to pull from. It then creates a Swift Package Dependencies section listing all your packages. Done!

You can see a nice demo of it at [RawWenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4167538-sharing-and-editing-swift-packages-with-swift-package-manager) (5 minutes video).

Comment: Too bad Xcode 10 doesn't support it. My Mac is too old and I cannot use Xcode 11.

Comment: @koen - if you don't mind working on the command line, you can use the SPM right there